# Solutions to Probability and Measure Theory - Robert Ash

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning

I've been looking for a book to self-study advanced probability with a measure theoretic approach. Although there are many questions such as this, most books suggested do not have a Solutions Manual, and the ones that do are often not with a measure theory approach, or are too basic.

Someone suggested me the book "Probability and Measure Theory" by Robert Ash. This seems like a very good book, but unfortunately the solutions are not for all exercises. The author's claim to have an Instructor's Manual. But unfortunately they have passed away.

I was wondering if anyone would have such manual and could share. If not, I would really appropriate suggestion on books with complete solutions to the exercises.

Comment: What would be a legitimate need for complete solutions at this level?  You need to spend the time thinking about and doing the exercises.

Comment: It really helps me out to actually evaluate if my solutions are indeed correct. The books with solutions are the ones that by far help me the most. Schilling’s book helped me tons to better understand Measure Theory.

Comment: at the level of the book you dont need or want solutions to the exercises. In any case, if you get stuck at some point, put your work here and we will help you

Comment: The measure theory in this book is light, but it does give a solid introduction: https://books.google.com/books/about/Probability_and_Random_Processes.html?id=G3ig-0M4wSIC There's also it's companion https://books.google.com/books/about/One_Thousand_Exercises_in_Probability.html?id=SQqTo8cwx1QC but maybe you dont need 1000 solved exercises :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I’ve read some of Grimmett’s, but I’m looking for something more advanced. Cheers